# Why is the getURL("www.zhoyosoft.com") function not working in Flash CS3?

Tags: flash

I am beginner of flash developer i dont know why the getURL("www.zhoyosoft.com") function is not working in Flash CS3, it throws error (Call to a possibly undefined method getURL) when opening a new browser window. Can Anyone help?

Comment: Whats the error your getting?

Comment: 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getURL.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the http:// like this.

```
getUrl("http://www.zhoyosoft.com")
```

Or since your using ActionScript3 try this:

```
var url:String = "http://www.zhoyosoft.com";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
try {
  navigateToURL(request, '_blank');
} catch (e:Error) {
  trace("Error occurred!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much MR.bendewey

Comment: Sorry bendewey . it not worked . 
it shows Call to a possibly undefined method getURL. error

Answer (score 3):

as like URLRequest.url, the destination must include the protocol

```
getURL("http://www.zhoyosoft.com");
```

EDIT: Okay apparently you are using AS3 and not AS2. getURL() was replaced with navigateToURL() in AS3. You can implement getURL() like this:

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public static function getURL(url:String, window:String = null):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url), window);
}
```

Comment: i tried but it shows 
it shows Call to a possibly undefined method getURL. error

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the location where the flash application is embedded does not have the `parameter: <param name=“allowScriptAccess” value=“never” />`

MySpace and most other websites that allow users to embed widgets block getURL. The reason is that getURL can be used to execute javascript in the context of the current user and site.

Answer (score 2):

Ben is right, but you can also write it as 1 line:

```
  navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.zhoyosoft.com"), "_blank");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
and
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        href="http://www.anothersite.com/thing.swf"
        AllowScriptAccess="always">
</embed>
```

source: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/changes-allowscriptaccess-default-flash-player.html

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your problem is because newer versiones of Adobe Flash Player (from 9.0.115.0) changed by default a security policy making the GetURL() and fscommand() methods not to work.

To make them work you need to change the embed object attribute AllowScriptAccess to "always". It is set by defaut as "sameDomain". You can find more informatino regarding this issue on Adobe website: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403183.html#main_DIAGNOSIS

In case this is not the problem, check publishing settings window on the Flash tab at the drop down option that lets you choose wether local access or network acces.

If not, here you have a nice and complete explanation on GetURL method for AS 2.0:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001180.html

Don't know exactly how/what are you going to use/implement this for, but I hope this info can help you.